# Activating new Snapping feature in ArcGIS Engine while editing features and vertices?

Tags: arcobjects, editing, arcgis-engine, snapping, vertices

I'm working on new Snapping Capability of ArcGIS Engine. 
I want to use snapping capability using `ISnappingEnvironment` class while users are editing a feature or moving vertices.
I tried `IPointSnapper.CacheShapes()` and set the `FeatureSelection` of `IMap` as argument of type `GeometryBag`  but I dont know when I should cache features and clear it or update cache.
We are using `ControlsEditingEditToolClas` control for editing features and I want to use new snapping with this tool or other available options.